# setRedirect(true) in wicket 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I have code something like this, So how can I write in wicket 6.x or 7.x
1.

```
catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("**** Exception ***********");
                setRedirect(true);
                log.errorException(e);
                showErrorMsg(getLocalizer().getString("request.process.page.error", this));
            }
```

2.

```
if (admin != null && admin.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(aId) == false) {

                    log.error("UserId do not match");
                    setRedirect(true);
                    showErrorMsg(getLocalizer().getString("internal.user.gccverf.auth.failed", this));

                }
```

I have method like this

```
private void showErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
            setResponsePage(new ErrorPage(this.getPage(), getLocalizer().getString("label.applicaiton.error.page", this), errorMsg));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `setRedirect(true);`.

Another way is to replace it with: `setResponsePage(getPage().getPageClass(), getPage().getPageParameters())`.  This will tell Wicket to create a new instance of the current page's class and render it. In this case it is important that `showErrorMsg()` uses `Session#error()` otherwise the error won't be available for the next page.

Comment: You mean to say like this?

catch (Exception e) {
 log.error("**** Exception ***********");
    
setResponsePage(getPage().getPageClass(), getPage().getPageParameters());
log.errorException(e);
    showErrorMsg(getLocalizer().getString("request.process.page.error", this));
   }

Comment: martin meant to say `getSession().error(Your error msg );`You have to try like this

Comment: You mean

catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("**** Exception ***********");
    

setResponsePage(getPage().getPageClass(),getPage().getPageParameters());

log.errorException(e);
    
getSession().error("request.process.page.error");
    
   }

Comment: No buddy  try  like this `getSession().error(showErrorMsg());`

Comment: is it like this?

getSession().error(getLocalizer().getString("request.process.page.error", this));

 I am really confused buddy, I need to call that userdefined method showErrorMsg(String errorMsg) or not.

Comment: @S.P.ROOPESH yes that is fine.